# React Router Dom 5.1.2 — Tabs support

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react-router-dom, and I'm trying to create a tabs menu, with a different route for each tab. 
I'm trying to keep the tabs state persistent between tabs switching by keeping the hidden tabs mounted. How can I achieve this? React router remounts each component every time the route switches even when using the render prop as per the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func).

My contact component has an internal state, and when I navigate to another tab, it's unmounted so the state is lost

```
      <Route path={`${path}`} exact render={() => <Home />} />
      <Route path={`${path}/profile`} render={() => <Profile />} />
      <Route path={`${path}/contact`} render={() => <Contact />} />
```

Here is a codesandbox for the example : https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lake-vhdby?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain the state in localStorage upon unmount and repopulate it in initialState

```
const Contact = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count")));

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted");
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
    return () => {
      localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    };
  }, [count]);
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
      You're on the Contact Tab. You pressed me {count} times
    </div>
  );
};
```

Another solution is to not maintain state in contact component but in App component and pass it on to Contact as props

```
<Route path={`${path}/contact`} render={(routerProps) => <Contact {...routeProps} count={count} setCount={setCount}/>} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the second solution !